# Keep getting a segmentation fault after tried to clear the buffer?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, function-pointers

Hi I was writing a simple code to help my self understand function pointer, but then I ran into another problem trying to clear the buffer because of the "\n" character being carried over, I have tried attempting to clear the buffer but ran into a another problem when i run the code i get a segmentation fault  when the else statement is true, why is this? can someone guide me in a way I can clear the buffer or a better method of handling this please and thank you.

```
               /*
                *      funcptrs.c
                *
                *      Program to demonstrate the use of function pointers
                *
                *      by Mvitagames
                */
                #include <stdio.h>
                #include <stdlib.h>

                static void goodbye() {

                  printf("\nPress ENTER to exit: ");
                  fflush(stdin);
                  getchar();

                }

                static int add(int a, int b) { return a + b;}

                static int subtract (int a, int b) { return a - b;}

                int main() {
                  int  i, j;
                  int  result;
                  int  (*func_ptr)(int , int );
                  int ch;
                  char buf[BUFSIZ];

                  atexit(goodbye);

                  printf("Please enter the first number: ");
                  scanf("%d", &i);
                  printf("Please enter the second number: ");
                  scanf("%d", &j);


                  while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);

                  printf("Would you like to add or subtract (a/s)? ");
                  if (getchar() == 'a')
                    func_ptr = add;
                  else
                    //printf("I got here");
                    func_ptr = subtract;

                   result = func_ptr(i,j);

                   printf("The result is %d\n", result);


                   return (0);
                  }
```

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` causes undefined behaviour. Other than that I don't see any problems. What input did you use to generate the segfault?

Comment: I entered 2 for the first parameter and 2 for the second and choose s so that the subtract function can be called, but yeah I forgot to remove the fflush(stdin) which is causing the undefined behavior. Regardless I've just removed the fflush(stdin); but I keep getting the same result of the subtract function being called regardless whether i choose a or b?

Comment: So you don't get the segfault anymore?  Your code works fine for me, doing: `2 <enter> 3 <enter> a <enter>`  generates `The result is 5`

Comment: try `void goodbye(void)`

Comment: I dont get the segfault anymore, but how did you get 2<enter> 3 <enter> a <enter> to result in 5, because i am running my code on bash but when i choose a i get a blank line, but when i choose b i actually get the number for example 2<enter> 2<enter> s<enter> is giving me 0 which the right answer, but the a<enter> is just giving me a blank line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use `fgets` to read lines of input and then use `sscanf` to do any conversions.  This avoids the problem where `scanf` leaves stray characters in the input buffer.  The resulting code looks like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXL 1024
static char line[MAXL];

static void goodbye() {

    printf("\nPress ENTER to exit: ");
    fgets( line, MAXL, stdin );
}

static int GetIntFromUser( char *prompt )
{
    int result;

    printf( "%s", prompt );
    fflush(stdout);

    if ( fgets( line, MAXL, stdin ) == NULL )
        exit( 1 );
    if ( sscanf(line, "%d", &result) != 1 )
        exit( 1 );

    return( result );
}

static char GetCharFromUser( char *prompt )
{
    char result;

    printf( "%s", prompt );
    fflush(stdout);

    if ( fgets( line, MAXL, stdin ) == NULL )
        exit( 1 );
    if ( sscanf(line, " %c", &result) != 1 )
        exit( 1 );

    return( result );
}

static int add(int a, int b) { return a + b;}

static int subtract (int a, int b) { return a - b;}

int main() {
    int  i, j;
    int  result;
    int  (*func_ptr)(int , int );
    char ch;

    atexit(goodbye);

    i = GetIntFromUser( "Please enter the first number: " );
    j = GetIntFromUser( "Please enter the second number: " );
    ch = GetCharFromUser( "Would you like to add or subtract (a/s)? " );

    if ( ch == 'a' )
        func_ptr = add;
    else
        func_ptr = subtract;

    result = func_ptr(i,j);

    printf("The result is %d\n", result);

    return (0);
}
```

Comment: thank so much for your help! Is there a simpler way of solving this issue without having so many if statements?

Comment: @mvitagames Yup error checking in C tends to obscure the actual code.  One way to clean things up is with a subroutine. I'll update the answer.